# How do you get the two previous url in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url

This is what I did to retrieve that the url the user clicked to open my webpage.

```
var oldURL = document.referrer; 
alert(oldURL);
```

However, I need to retrieve the 2 (two) last url clicked by this user before ending up on my webpage.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: sorry, i've totally misunderstood your question. so, deleting my answer.

Comment: Do you control the sites that you're wanting to track? Because if not then you probably can't especially if they're served up via HTTPS as the referrer will usually be blank so even tracking one page prior may not be possible. If you control the site(s) or if the site owners would be willing to install a script you could either use something like google analytics cross-domain tracking or set your own 3rd party tracking cookies or decorate links to your site with additional data etc. Without the ability to add scripts to their site you're hands are quite tied for the most part unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Has what I know is not possible, except if you go through a plugin like **history.js**,
But you can see the object **window.history** can be help you.

MDN :[history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

HISTORY.JS : [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get last two URL, you can only get the last URL. But you can use plugin like [History.Js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)